# I got this error for auto _Suggest and error is "Object reference not set an instance of an object "

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Public Sub auto_Suggest(ByVal member As String, ByVal table As String, ByVal txt As Object)
    Try
        dta = New DataTable
        'open the connection
        conn.Open()
        'holds the data in the database
        With cmda
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "select " & member & " from " & table
        End With
        '''''''''''''''fill data in the table
        daa.SelectCommand = cmda
        daa.Fill(dta)

        ''function of autocomplete
        Dim r As DataRow
        txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()


        For Each r In dta.Rows
            txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(r.Item(0).ToString)

        Next
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    ''''close the connection
    conn.Close()
    daa.Dispose()

End Sub




Private Sub Stock_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        'call a public sub
        'the job_id is the field of a table , the employees is the name of a table and a textbox is an object
        auto_Suggest("ItemName", "stock", TxtItemName)

        Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's good to employ a "use it and lose it" approach and take advantage of Using blocks to automatically dispose of connections, commands, and readers. See the example below.

Second, please set a breakpoint on the first line after the Try statement and step through your source in the debugger. If the exception is reached, inspect the ex variable and potentially the ex.InnerException (if any).

Last, the example here uses SQLConnection and SQLCommand (SQL Server). Just swap out whatever library you are using for MySQL and you should be good to go.

```
Public Sub auto_Suggest(connectionString As String, member As String, table As String, txt As TextBox)
    Try
        txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()

        Using cn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            cn.Open()

            Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & member & " FROM " & table, cn)
                Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While dr.Read
                        txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(dr(member).ToString)
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Error 1 Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined. D:\Pharmacy\Pharmacy\Surgical  Stock.vb 125 28 Pharmacy                               and   Error 2 Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined. D:\Pharmacy\Pharmacy\Surgical  Stock.vb 128 33 Pharmacy
and  I got this errrors i don't know what is this eror

Comment: Thank you soo much i got it ya thanks a lot  Can you help me for this work   Iwood like to reduct stock quantity when i seel the product .If you like please help me  ihave done like this

Comment: cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO sale VALUES (null,'" & txt_billno.Text.ToString() & "','" & txtdate.Text.ToString() & "','" & TxtCName.Text.ToString() & "','" & txtItCode.Text.ToString() & "','" & TxtItName.Text.ToString() & "','" & Val(txtQty.Text) & "','" & txtPrice.Text.ToString() & "','" & Val(txtFreIsue.Text) & "','" & txtAmount.Text.ToString &  "')", conn) CtQty = TxtQTYSTOCK.Text -sellQity
                   cmd = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `pharmacy`.`stock` SET `Quantity`='" & CurrentQuantity & "' WHERE  `stock`.`ItemCode` = '" & txtItemCode.Text.ToString() & "'", conn)

Comment: Here's how to debug SQL code - set a breakpoint prior to each SQL command executing. At the breakpoint, copy the command text exactly as you have it in each MySqlCommand("{command text}"). Then print the text and you should see the resulting SQL statement. Inspect and/or run this statement directly for the db. You will see any issues quickly, I guarantee. Also, just as an aside, where you have statements like txt_billno.Text.ToString(), .Text properties are already strings so no need to have .ToString() there :). If you like, post the full code as a new question and I will take a look at it.